# Does a custom control inherit base class INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a base generic custom control (grandparent). In order for the designer to display inheriting controls without problem, I first inherit (parent) from grandparent, and finally I inherit from parent. The child control is the control used on the forms.

If I implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the grandparent control, will the child be recognized as implementing this interface?

Comment: Yes it will be. but it is your responsibility to raise the events for new properties you add in your derived class.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel totaly a comprehensive answer. why comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will be. but it is your responsibility to raise the events for new properties you add in your derived class

see more [C# Language Specification: Interface implementation inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664593%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I don't like to see so many answers saying the same thing. In this case (yes is the answer). But, it is better to be as an answer, I think you don't mind me updating your answer with my comment. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. Every child of inheritance gets all public or protected variables and methods from their parents. For example, all objects get the same methods as the object class.

For more information check out [MSDN: Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173149%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)